# Nestjs Logger, how to add milliseconds to every logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, logging, nestjs

I would like to know how to add milliseconds to every logs printed by the Nestjs Logger.

And if possible, is there a way to bind the Nestjs Logger to each request/response like Fastify do with Pino ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can simply create a new `ConsoleLogger` inside a middleware to log incoming requests. I don't know if there is a fancier solution.

Comment: Have a look at the issue https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4262, which seem to have been implemented under https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/5681